# How to prevent a thread from switching?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a simple question about multithreading.

I want a thread in the application to finish its task before it switches to thead from the same application?

I know it will switch with other threads from other applications. However, is it possible for thread to keep control and not switch with others threads originating from the same application?

Comment: You need to show parts from your code that are relevant.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the thread to run with higher priority than other threads of the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do it is you block the other threads till the thread you want to finish unblocks them, use synchronization mechanisms like [`ManualResetEventSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim(v=vs.110).aspx), [`AutoResetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx), or [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.110).aspx) to control the flow of your threads.